# Save partial data from model to db MVC4

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, model

I have a model

```
public partial class User
{
    public int user_id { get; set; }
    public virtual string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string salt { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public sbyte status { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime creation_date { get; set; }
}
```

i wanto to give the user the possibility to change his mail from a page

so i create my controller

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Setup()
    {
        //retrieve the object user
        return View(CustomDbFunctions.GetUserEntity(User, db));
    }
```

then in my view

```
@Html.EditorFor(u => u.email)
```

but when i save my modification in the db using

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Setup(User user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            db.Entry(user).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Redirect("Index");
        }
        return View(user);
    }
```

the system return an error, because the object user contains ONLY the modified mail. All others properties (i.e. User_id, password) are gone.
How can i send back to the db the entire object properly modified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Update something with entity framework you have to first get the entity from DB:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var existingUser = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.user_id == user.user_id);

        existingUser.email = user.email;

        db.SaveChanges();
        return Redirect("Index");
    }
```

For this to work you also need to have in your view, inside the form, something like

```
@Html.HiddenFor(u => u.user_id)
```

However, I suppose you have the Id of the user somewhere in the Session. You should use it from there and not from the hidden field, because a hacker could change the value in the hidden tag and edit another user's email.

Comment: Or `db.Users.Find(user.user_id);`

Answer (score 0):

If you use model binding of mvc, then you need to use the other properties as hidden field, that way while posting back the whole object will be returned instead of only email.

Comment: He only wants to allow the modification of the Email. If all the fields are in hidden fields, then the user could manually edit the hidden fields and edit everything in the User object.

Comment: For him to be able to do any sorts of editing he at least need to keep Id as hidden field, which makes the whole situation not so secure. I don't see a problem in exposing all the fields, where primary key needs to be exposed.

Comment: You don't want to save data such as Salt or Status or Username directly from the User input. The Id is necessary, and the worst he can do is to change the Id and update the email for another user. However, the Id should be saved to session after login, and used from there in this case, not passed to a hidden field.